# How to check existing Worklight version installed :- Consumer or Enterprise

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to download a fix pack from fix central and i have two options consumer or enterprise, Is there a way to check existing WL server installation is consumer edition or enterprise edition depending on which i can start the download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical difference between the Enterprise and Consumer editions.
The difference is in your license terms with IBM. So whichever you download, it's the same.

So if you want to know which to download - contact your Business unit and ask them which you should download (even though technically they are the same...). Don't mess with the Legal departments. :-)

Read more here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/getstart/c_wl_editions.html

Comment: There is no command because the difference is **legal** and not **technical**.

Comment: 1) This is a legal-related question, not programming. Talk with your managers. 2) And also, try to google first: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/getstart/c_wl_editions.html